# amplify graphql no credentials error in cypress test

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, graphql, cypress, aws-amplify

```
Cypress.Commands.add("gencert" as any, async () => {
  const log = Cypress.log({
    displayName: "GENERATING CERTIFICATE",
    autoEnd: false,
  });

  const awsconfig = {
    aws_user_pools_id: "...",
    aws_user_pools_web_client_id: "...",
  };

  Auth.configure(awsconfig);

  const response = await API.graphql({
    query: addCertificate,
    variables: {
      id: 3,
      nr: 5,
    },
  });
});
```

I have a custom cypress command to make a graphql request. However i always get a `No credentials` error. The console outputs following warning: `ensure credentials error No Cognito Identity pool provided for unauthenticated access`

Before the test, i do a programmatic login, so `console.log(Auth.configure());` gives me the correct user_pools id. `identityPoolId` is undefined, because i did not specify it, because we dont use identityPools, we use userPools.

The request inside the application works fine. It is only not working inside the cypress test.